# how to store the large amount data in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, window

in android for storing data we are using array list,hash map...etc.
in windows how we save the large amount of data? what about collections in windows phone development. Please any one explain me how to store the data in windows phone 8.1 development.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the main type of collections available in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

All of them can be used in Windows Phone.